# Setting click event on a dynamically created view in view pager

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, onclicklistener, ontouchlistener

I am having trouble to set click event on a dynamically created view in a `Fragment` in `ViewPager` with `FragmentPagerAdapter`. These views are being added dynamically to `Fragment`'s layout. But neither `onClick` event or `onTouch` event does not work. Any idea how to solve this problem?

In `Fragment`:

```
  for (int i = 0; i < itemCount; i++) {
            ImageView item = (ImageView) inflater.inflate(R.layout.category_item, null);
            item.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
            item.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    Log.i("button", "clicked");
                }
            });
            item.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    Log.i("button", "onTouch");
                    return false;
                }
            });

            rl.addView(item);
        }
```

Inflating in `Fragment`:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_category, null);
        return view;
    }
```

In `category_item.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ImageView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >


</ImageView>
```

Comment: Are you inflating the fragment?

Comment: @DovD. in FragmentPager adapter, I'm loading fragments on getItem(int position) method. And for each fragment, I'm inflating different layout.

Comment: Please post inflating code. Also, at what point are these views being added to the fragment?

Comment: @DovD. In a DialogFragment which is shown on click event of a button in the Fragment, user chooses some categories and then DialogFragment is cancelled. Then I'm adding images of these categories to the Fragment.

Comment: And rl is the already displayed relative layout in the fragment?

Comment: Did you try requestLayout on the fragments view?

Comment: Maybe you need to .bringToFront() each imageview.

Comment: @DovD. I found the reason. I do some animation operations before clicking them. On click event is in the old position. I click new position. So on click event is not working. If i click old position, it works. Thank you for your reply, time and attention.